# Catch EndpointNotFound in Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

How catch `NoEndpointFoundException` in Spring WS?

By default `MessageDispatcher.dispath()` throws `NoEndpointFoundException` in case of absence appropriate Endpoint but then `WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection()` just hides the exception. In my point I should catch it by myself.

Is it good idea to add custom EndpointMapping via `MessageDispatcher.getEndpointMappings().add()` and throws exception in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out following solution:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class NoEndpointFoundEndpointMapping implements EndpointMapping {

    @Override
    public EndpointInvocationChain getEndpoint(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {

        throw new MyCustomException(...);
    }
}
```